# .htaccess rewrite site with #item in URL for direct file access

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I hope someone can help me, please. I created a site with ajax and I want if someone visits `www.example.com/example1.html` to get redirected to 
`www.example.com/#items/example1.html`I need to redirect them to the `/#items` at the beginning of the URL for many HTML files because if someone visits the direct HTML file the site is broken (no CSS & JS is in the HTML files) because I created the HTML files only for ajax calls and want to prevent direct URL access for better user experience. I hope someone here might know how to get such a redirect using a `.htaccess` file.

**EDIT**
I tried this before with no success. I don't know how to do this redirect, to be honest :)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#items/$1.html
```

Comment: Please show how you have tried to solve your problem and what specific issue you had with your attempt. Since you know that you need a htaccess redirect, you should try to do it yourself before asking here.

Comment: Thanks, I edited now my question and added now the code I tried to work on. I don't know how to do this redirect, to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /#items/$1.html [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but how to get this redirect for all HTML items? I edited my question to show the code snippet I tried to get working. I try to redirect all `.html` files at once and not one by one if possible. Because there are many `.html` files that need this redirect.

Comment: just edited, you need to add RewriteRule Flags (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html), [NE] for no escape (# is escaped if rewrite), [R=301] for redirect permanently

Comment: Thanks but after implementing your code it broke all ajax calls on my site and it went in a loop loading with many errors. It would be great if there would be an option like an if statement if the direct URL get,'s accessed then add `/#items` in the URL if it's not already added or something similar so it won't go to an endless loop in the ajax call.

Comment: then you need to think about the rewrite logic, to provide the conditions in which the `RewriteRule` should apply, not just paste the `RewriteRule` in the .htaccess